# Video is not downloading from a URL

Tags: java, android

i want to download video from URL my function is as below

```
String fileURL = "http://192.168.1.2/UserFiles/Videos/OutputVideo/Birthday%20Bash5tV3fgjf4Sfi11sC.mp4";

String fileName = "Abc.mp4";

public void downloadFile(String fileURL, String fileName){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try
        {
            URL u = new URL(fileURL);
            URLConnection ucon = u.openConnection();
            //Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
            // uses 3KB download buffer
            File file =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/Planetskool/Media/Videos/"+fileName);
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 5);
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] buff = new byte[5 * 1024];

            //Read bytes (and store them) until there is nothing more to read(-1)
            int len;
            while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1)
            {
                outStream.write(buff,0,len);
            }

            //clean up
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            inStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

its downloading video in 0kb whats wrong with this

Comment: is this url provide downloading video on browser ?

Comment: url provide downloading video on browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use async method to download file from URL.

Answer (score 0):

Three things might be happened

1. Missing Internet permission
2. Missing Write external storage permission
3. "/Planetskool/Media/Videos/" Directory not exist, Create dir first.
4. http://192.168.1.2 it is not internet URL check your URL